# [Objective-C]Edit UILabel without hiding keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to copy the content in a UILabel but without hiding the keyboard, the problem is that when I show the menu of copy in the label the label becomes first responder and the keyboard resign, but I want to do that without hiding the keyboard, is there a way to do that?

Comment: I had the same problem but I didn't found a better solution than a custom implementation of the copy menu ( with uilongpressgesturerecognizer and UIPasteboard)

Comment: ok, you mean using a custom uimenucontroller? or just using the gesture recognizer and then the pasteboard?

Comment: i used a simple uiview (styled like a uimenucontroller) with a copy button

Comment: but this might be a much better solution: https://github.com/jaredsinclair/UIMenuControllerTest

Comment: A little confused as to what you're trying to do here, would it be possible to make your situation a little simpler by instead of using a UILabel, to instead use a UITextField?

Comment: hmm.. i dont know if what i did is effective for this, but i copied using `dispatch_async` in the background, quite work for me though... hmm..

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible with `UILabel`.

You should use `UITextField` for that. Just disable editing.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you can't do that. But I think you can have a work around for that. Instead of not hiding the keyboard, why don't keep track the current active text field and then active it after user press `copy`. You can use `UIPasteboardChangedNotification` to know when user pressed `copy`. For example:

```
self.lastActiveTextField = aTextField

-(void)pasteBoardDidChange:(NSNotification*)notif
{
     [self.lastActiveTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so u r looking something like this project.

**UILabel with UIKeyInput protocol implementation**

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQEditableLabel

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is not possible, there can be only one first responder at any time. If the keyboard is shown because of another UI element, then when you try to copy the content from UILabel, the OS has to transfer first responder from other element to UILabel, as there is no need of keyboard for UILabel, the keyboard will hide automatically. So, you have to make changes to your elements to fix this problem or use third party UI elements who can fix your problem.

Answer (score -3):

Every UIView component has a method called: canBecomeFirstResponder. He is read only, but you can subclass the UI object and override the getter:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return false;
}
```

I didn't do the test, but if the "become first responder" is the problem, that should solve it.

Comment: Ok, that way the textview doesn't become first responder, and the keyboard doesn't hide, but, the issue here is that I need to show the select all | copy menu, and with this it doesn't appear